# No tray icon after run compiled program

Tags: qt, icons, system-tray

When I run program from Qt Creator icon is visible in tray, but when I run compiled program from "relased" folder I see process of application but no icon in tray

```
QSystemTrayIcon * tray = new QSystemTrayIcon( QIcon( "ok.png" ), this );
tray->setContextMenu( trayIconMenu );
tray->show();
tray->setVisible( true );
```

Comment: Try to use absolute path to your icon instead relative. Or use resource file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your image file ok.png was not deployed properly.
I would avoid the recommendation of using an absolute path.
Please introduce yourself with the Qt-ressource-system: it adds a layer ob indirection to manage ressources like graphics, sound files, .. and Qt will take care of proper deployment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: Ad image to resources help. Thank you